# Is a locally constant etale sheaf determined by its sections over finite etale neighbhorhoods?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a connected scheme, and $F,F'$ two finite locally constant sheaves on $(Sch/S)_{et}$

We may restrict $F,F'$ to sheaves (or at least functors) on the subcategory of $(Sch/S)$ consisting of finite etale morphisms $T\rightarrow S$. Suppose the restrictions of $F,F'$ to this subcategory are isomorphic as functors. Must $F,F'$ be isomorphic as sheaves on $(Sch/S)_{et}$?

Comment: Of course the answer is yes if $F,F'$ are LCC. If they are literally just locally constant, possibly with infinite value group, then I don't know—I've never thought about such things. But, it would seem semi-unlikely to me. Namely, note that if $\pi_1(S)=0$ then $S_{\text{Fet}}$ is just the category of covers of the form $\displaystyle \bigsqcup_i X_i\to S$ where $X_i\to S$ is an isomorphism. In particular, for any sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $S_{\text{et}}$ we have that $\mathcal{F}\mid_{S_{\text{Fet}}}$ is just the constant sheaf associated to $\mathcal{F}(S)$.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to say finite locally constant. Why is it so obvious?

Comment: Because every LCC sheaf is representable by a finite étale cover. The result then follows from Yoneda.

Comment: What does LCC stand for?

Comment: Did you try googling it? :P It stands for locally constant constructible. It just means locally constant with finite value sets.

Comment: By the way, when I googled it (to make sure something came up), the first response is a mathoverflow post that you've edited. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Ahhh nice. I forgot you could restrict to a smaller category with yoneda. Nice.

Comment: Haha usually I just say finite locally constant, so I was wondering if the second C meant "finite" in French or something

Comment: I mean, it's not that you can apply Yoneda to a subcategory, it's more like you have the following. If you have a category $\mathscr{C}$ and a full subcategory $\mathscr{D}$ then for two objects $X,Y$ of $\mathscr{D}$ the Hom functors $h_X$ and $h_Y$ are isomorphic in the presheaf category $\widehat{\mathscr{C}}$ if and only if they are isomorphic in the presheaf category $\widehat{\mathscr{D}}$. In particular, Yoneda's lemma sees nothing outside of $\mathscr{D}$ when talking about isomorphisms in $\mathscr{D}$, but since isomorphism in $\mathscr{D}$ is equivalent

Comment: t isomorphism in $\mathscr{C}$, it's enough to think about $mathscr{D}$. :)

Comment: Right right exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To record Alex Youcis's answer, the answer is of course yes and follows from the fact that finite locally constant sheaves on $S$ are representable by schemes finite etale over $S$, together with the Yoneda lemma.